# WebStorm (2021.3) auto-completion and auto-import not working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webstorm, tsconfig

I have created two TypeScript projects: one is a library (named "**ts-boot**") and the other one is the main project ("**ts-server**") consuming the library. During development I use npm link to automatically fetch code changes.

The code is running fine, but WebStorm IDE (2021.3) has some problems.

The main problem is, that auto-completion for updated code works only after restarting the IDE. After auto-completion works it still does not add the import statement. And after adding it manually it is underlined red saying "TS2307: Cannot find module '...' or its corresponding type declarations.". tsc and node do not complain and the code runs fine.

[image: Autocompletion does not add import]

[image: Imports are underlined with error Module not found]

In WebStorm I marked `node_modules/ts-boot` as included to add it to the index.

I'm confused where WebStorm gets its information about what modules to auto-complete and import. I have been struggling with this problem for days and can't find any solution.

Important to me is that I want to keep the long path in the import statement. Many projects use one large declaration file with all the exports in it, but that may lead to name collisions in bigger projects.

**tsconfig** of "**ts-boot**":

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig** of "**ts-server**":

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./target",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Happy holidays in advance!

**Edit 1:**

`node_modules/ts-boot/lib` contains a .d.ts file for each .ts file:

[image]

`tsc -p .` in the root of `ts-server` runs without errors:

```
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/projects/dev/workspace/js/ts-server$ npm run build

> ts-server@1.0.0 build
> tsc -p .

xxx@xxx:~/Documents/projects/dev/workspace/js/ts-server$
```

Comment: does the `node_modules/ts-boot` include `.d.ts` files with module definitions? What is a result of running `tsc -p .` in terminal in the `ts-server` root folder (where its `tsconfig.json` is located)?

Comment: @lena Hi lena, I have added the answers to your questions at the bottom.